# Picker View data disappears too quickly

Tags: swiftui, picker, combine

**Scenario:**

1. Application is tab-based; one tab is a container view having a 'Picker (Data) View'.
2. Picker View: the Picker is initially loaded with data via @State -> @Binder.
3. A 'Front Page' (Greetings) View is initially displayed over the Picker View within a ZStack{}.
4. User Acknowledges the front page which disappears to reveal the Picker View (#2).

**Note:** Data is **received** by the Picker per debug check. 
The hidden Picker View shows the initial data.

**Problem:** 
The revealed Picker View **becomes empty**; *after dismissing* the Front Page/View.

The following is a debug listing via BreakPoint of data:

[image]

**Observation:** 
I want to access the data source ASAP to populate the Picker View to avoid having the user wait for the data.  Hence the data is initially access prior to revealing the Picker View.

However, 
the Picker View apparently gets re-rendered just prior to being displayed.

**Note:** I see the **populated** picker page if I comment-out the front-page code.

I've added a boolean filter to avoid calling the Picker with an empty data payload.

**Question:**

How do I make the data more permanent; that is, stay until it is dismissed?

Do I have to make a concrete copy of a @Binding variable?

Comment: Would you provide reproducible example?

Comment: The app is big; I'll try to recreate with a simple version. And get back.

Answer (score 0):

Non-SwiftUI fix:

Use a **Singleton** for the ***persistent data vector***; and hence not influenced by the life of the controlling View:

```
final class DataSource {
    static let shared = DataSource()
    var myVar:String = "Hello World"
    var countryNames: [String]?
}
```

[image]

This is so simple that it's elegant. 
Still, I would like to use combine here, but the data life is too volatile.

I plan to review this paradigm further into my project as I become more proficient in Combine.

If anyone has a SwiftUI/Combine method of accessing, holding/sharing data that doesn't require a Singleton object, please post.